# What happens in the kernel when the process accesses an address just allocated with brk/sbrk?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

This is actually a theoretical question about memory management. Since different operating systems implement things differently, I'll have to relieve my thirst for knowledge asking how things work in only one of them :( Preferably the open source and widely used one: Linux.

Here is the list of things I know in the whole puzzle:

- `malloc()` is user space. libc is responsible for the syscall job (calling `brk`/`sbrk`/`mmap`...). It manages to get big chunks of memory, described by ranges of virtual addresses. The library slices these chunks and manages to respond the user application requests.
- I know what `brk`/`sbrk` syscalls do. I know what 'program break' means. These calls basically push the program break offset. And this is how libc gets its virtual memory chunks.
- Now that user application has a new virtual address to manipulate, it simply writes some value to it. Like: `*allocated_integer = 5;`. Ok. Now, what? If `brk`/`sbrk` only updates offsets in the process' entry in the process table, or whatever, how the physical memory is actually allocated?
- I know about virtual memory, page tables, page faults, etc. But I wanna know exactly how these things are related to this situation that I depicted. For example: is the process' page table modified? How? When? A page fault occurs? When? Why? With what purpose? When is this 'buddy algorithm' called, and this `free_area` data structure accessed? (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html, section **3.4.1 Page Allocation**)

Comment: page table is modified in `sbrk/brk` syscall, so the user could access the memory legally(without segmentation fault). But physical page frame is allocated when page fault occurs for performance consideration.

Comment: so, when you create/merge VMAs, you actually create PTEs? I'm searching the source code for that part, but I can't find the point when PTEs are created...

Comment: see my answer, `brk` do not changes the page table. check [link1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/mmap.c#L2739), [link2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/mmap.c#L1058) and [link3](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/mmap.c#L686)

Comment: Thank you, it's very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after finally finding an excellent guide (http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/) and some hours digging the Linux kernel, I found the answers...

- Indeed, `brk` only pushes the virtual memory area.
- When the user application hits `*allocated_integer = 5;`, a page fault occurs.
- The [page fault routine](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1065) will [search](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1201) for the virtual memory area responsible for the address and then [call](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L1245) the page table handler.
- The [page table handler](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3352) goes through each level (2 levels in x86 and 4 levels in x86_64), allocating entries if they're not present ([2nd](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3364), [3rd](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3367) and [4th](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3405)), and then finally [calls](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3428) the real handler.
- The [real handler](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3285) **actually** [calls](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L3305) the [function](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/67944024c1cdd897e49a09b0d6af3ea38d1388ca/mm/memory.c#L2668) responsible for allocating page frames.